# How can I Webscrape in python with a website that uses AngularJS ng-include

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping

I'm very new to python and Webscraping, I am trying to get a list of products from a website- https://www.melaleuca.com/ProductStore/content/category?c=52 but I run into an issue when I encounter some AngularJS. I can get the stuff before with using simple code like

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

laundryUrl = "https://www.melaleuca.com/ProductStore/content/category?c=52"
r = requests.get(laundryUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
product = soup.find(class_="category-info-wrapper")
print(product)
```

But when I encounter ng-include I can no longer access the classes under them. When I use the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

laundryUrl = "https://www.melaleuca.com/ProductStore/content/category?c=52"
r = requests.get(laundryUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
product = soup.find(class_="product-card ng-scope)
print(product)
```

I get back "none"

---

I've never used angularJS but from what I've researched it looks like there is another html file in the html file, how do I access that and get the data? I've tried using Selenium as well and ran into the same problem.

---

The HTML when I inspect the page looks like this

```
<div class="category-info-wrapper"></div>
<ol class="mela-product-wrapper ng-scope" ng- 
include="'//cdnus.melaleuca.com/html/product-store/product-card-201905.html'">
<li id="_8219" class="product-card ng-scope" ng-repeat="product in products" 
ng-init="culture">
```

...

Comment: If the website is using JS to render it's contents (which an angular site will) you will have to use something like Selenium to scrape it as it will execute the JS. `BeautifulSoup` does not run any JS and just acts on the raw HTML response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL. This script uses `requests`/`json` module to parse it:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://api-us.melaleuca.com/search/v3'
params = {
    'id': 'products_by_category_facets',
    'index': 'en_us',
    'params': json.dumps(
        {"sortField":"","sortDir":"","from":0,"size":1000,"categoryId":"52","filters":[]}
    )
}
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.melaleuca.com/ProductStore/content/category?c=52'
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data to screen:
for h in data['hits']['hits']:
    s = BeautifulSoup(h['_source']['name']['enhanced'], 'html.parser')
    print(s.text)
    print(h['_source']['sku'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
EcoSense® Clean Home Pack Save over $38.00 
8219
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EcoSense Laundry Value 4-Pack with 96 Load bottles Save up to $10.00 
6012
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limited Time EcoSense Laundry Regular 4-Pack with 48 Load bottles Save $4.75
6013
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EcoSense® Kitchen Pack Save up to $4.00  (Mixing Spray Bottle not included)
8220
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EcoSense® Bathroom Pack Save $4.00  (Mixing Spray Bottles not included)
5679
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MelaSoft® Fabric Softener 96 Load 2-Pack Save $2.00
2154
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I'm trying to understand the code, but I don't get where you got the url "url = 'https://api-us.melaleuca.com/search/v3'" and also what
 "'params': json.dumps(
        {"sortField":"","sortDir":"","from":0,"size":1000,"categoryId":"52","filters":[]}
    )" 
means. Can you explain this please?

Comment: @AlexK I saw this URL in Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab. The page is loading the data from this URL and needs those paramaters. It's how the developers of this site made it, there isn't any standard in this, every site is different.